# Copy to first empty row of a different worksheet with Offset function

Tags: vba, excel

This macro is intended to via an Inputbox using Findstring, find a row, copy it to the first empty row of a different worksheet, and delete the row on the original worksheet.

```vb
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
    Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
    Rng.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox ("Niks gescrapt. Check of het B-nummer correct is.")
End If

End With
    MsgBox ("Logboek gescrapt.")
End If
End Sub
```

I get a syntax error on the Offset function.

```
Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).
```

Comment: Please add to your code example or tidy it up. You've got `End With` and `End If` with no starting condition. Which line is it failing on? What is wrong?

Comment: Excuse me Tom. Total code was too long, giving an error. I approved your edit. Line that it is failing on is; Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).

It works perfectly without this, but keeps overwriting the data found, and copied to another worksheet. To prevent this from happening i wanted to try it with the Offset function.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the offset. Don't you want to select it or assign it a value?

Comment: You're telling the offset to go 1 down on the Row and 1 to the left on the Column. As you're doing this in Column A there is no where for it to go giving you the error.

Comment: Tom, that was pretty stupid. Thank you for that correction.

@Alex4336, i want the Pasting function below it to look for the first empty row and paste there, instead of pasting in A2 everytime, overwriting everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in **column A**, so you **can't Offset minus one column** because **there is none other on the left**!

Try your code with `Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` and it'll work! ;)

And your code would always paste on A2 which is probably not the purpose, so here is the corrected version :

```
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("ScrapLogboek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Rng.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    MsgBox ("Niks gescrapt. Check of het B-nummer correct is.")
End If

End With
    MsgBox ("Logboek gescrapt.")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're my hero of the day!
Thank you for teaching me how to handle the Offset, and even correcting my code. Bon Merci!